# Classification algorithm and big text field

Tags: classification, text-mining

My question is straightforward: I want to do statistical classification in a database, mostly of floats, but one of the fields of the data is a big text. By *big* I mean up to 1000 words.

What is the best way to deal with that?

**UPDATED**: It's supposed to be *supervised learning*: I have some rows that have the values "Closed" and "Not Closed", and want to estimate this row for the other ones.

Comment: Could you describe what do you mean by 'classification'? Usually classification is understood as a supervised learning task, while in your case you seem to talk about unsupervised learning (clustering)?

Comment: @danas.zuokas: updated the question!

Answer (score 1):

You need to quantify text, that is to create additional variables from that text which would help classification. These might be the length of a text, the frequency of occurrence of certain words or phrases (like in spam filtering) and so on. It might even be the whole document-term matrix, but in this case you will have a lot of non informative variables so you need to think of some kind of regularization.